# How to compile an android app to 64bit

Tags: android, 64-bit

I came across the article that says all apps must be 64bit by August 2019

https://www.engadget.com/2017/12/19/android-apps-must-have-64-bit-support-by-august-2019/

and according to google, I found the following section

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

> **64-bit support requirement in 2019**.
>   In anticipation of future Android devices that support 64-bit code only, the Play Console will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions. This can be within a single APK or as one of the multiple APKs published.

So it's confirmed that new apps is required to provide 64bit version.

Now how do I go about compiling a 64bit version app? Is there any checkbox on Android studios where I can select to make an app 64bits?

Comment: If your app is entirely in java or kotlin you don't have to do anything. Those changes are related to native C/C++ libraries

Comment: "native libraries" is the clue in your quote. People abuse the word "NATIVE" TOO much, It should ONLY mean coded/complied directly for the processor, NOT something that runs in in a "virtual machine" like java (bytecode, of which java,kotlin and scala a just a few ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This change only affects apps that use "native code", ie code that compiles for the processor on the device, as opposed to being written in Java or Kotlin.

This will only be true for you if:

- You have written such native code (probably in C or C++) using the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)
- You use a third party library that has native code

If the former, then you should know how to target more processors ([See this page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)).
If the latter then you will need to talk to the developer of the third party library.

This [article](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) on the Android developer documentation site provides a good overview of how to identify whether your app is 64-bit compliant and what you need to do in case it is not.